# How does multiplication by a constant affect a Gumbel random variable

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, extreme-value-analysis

Suppose $X$ is a Gumbel (Type-1 extreme value) random variable with shape and scale parameters given by ($\mu$, $\sigma$). What is the distribution of $cX$, where $c$ is a constant?

Comment: If cX is still distributed Gumbel, here's how I would answer it. Var(X) = $\frac{\sigma^2 \pi^2}{6}$ so Var(cX) = $c^2$Var(X), implying that cX must have scale parameter equal to $c \sigma$. I assume that the shape parameter becomes $c \mu$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distribution will still be a Gumbel distribution but with parameters $(c\mu,c\sigma)$.

That is the case for either of the usual Gumbel Type 1 distributions.  For $Y=cX$ those have density functions:

$$\frac{e^{\frac{\alpha  c-y}{\beta  c}-e^{\frac{\alpha  c-y}{\beta  c}}}}{\beta  c}$$
and
$$\frac{e^{\frac{y-\alpha  c}{\beta  c}-e^{\frac{y-\alpha  c}{\beta  c}}}}{\beta  c}$$